# Which step in deriving the derivative of $sec(x)$ is wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I can't see any errors on the steps. But Step 3 makes me doubt my answer.
[image]

Comment: $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$, so what would you get for $\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right)$?  What does that suggest for steps 3 or 4?

Comment: @Henry that gives $\sec(x) \cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ by quotient rule. So there must be no error on the steps?

Comment: Unlike the other people here, I believe that each step os legit, and so I will opt for option D.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 using this method you can derive the derivative of a noncontinuous function.

Comment: Uh, so we have to make the statement "$\sec x$ is differentiable"?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 what's the reason why? I can't figure out the reason if the answer is D.

Comment: @Ultralegend5385 Either we have to prove "sec(x) is differentiable", or we have to list it as an assumption in the beginning.

Comment: @harpey1111 Because if we don't, then the conclusion might be false.

Answer (score 1):

The product rule: $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x) \cdot g(x)] = f'(x)g(x) +f(x)g'(x)$.

It's technically not actually always true. For example, try $f(x) = |x| = g(x)$ at $x = 0$.

The catch is that $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ must be defined. If they are, then it is true.

So the assumption in the above problem occurs at step 3. It assumes $\frac{d}{dx}[\sec(x)]$ is defined.

---

Edit: It seems there is debate of whether the fact "$\frac{d}{dx}[\sec(x)]$ is defined when sec$(x)$ is defined" is actually an assumption for this question. Consider if the question had been this one instead:

Below is an attempt to derive the derivative of $ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$} \\
-1, & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$}
\end{cases}\Bigr\}$ using the product rule. In which step, if any, does an error first appear?

Step 1) $f(x) \cdot f(x) = 1$

Step 2) $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x) \cdot f(x)] = 0$

Step 3) $f'(x)f(x) + f(x)f'(x) = 0$

Step 4) $f'(x) = 0$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x)$ is defined whenever $\sec(x)$ is defined. Moreover, since we are asked to derive the value of $\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x),$ it seems reasonable to assume we will only consider $x$ such that $\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x)$ is defined. If that is not a good assumption, then the error is in step $1$, since $\sec(x)$ itself also is undefined for every $x$ for which $\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: I don't understand this. Does that mean $\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x)$ is not defined there that's why step 3 has an error?

Comment: @harpey1111 You do know that $\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x)$ is indeed $\sec(x)\tan(x)$, right? No, I'm not saying there's an error, I'm saying there's an assumption. Now it just so happens that the assumption is correct, but none of the steps justify this.

Comment: @David K  First of all, we are not being asked to derive the value of sec(x), we are being asked to find any possible errors/assumptions in a derivation of the value of sec(x). Second of all, yes $\frac{d}{dx}[\sec(x)]$ is defined whenever $\sec(x)$ is defined, but that has not been established in the above proof, and given the context that the person is attempting to derive the derivative of $\sec(x)$, such an assumption is not warranted. Last of all, the question is careful enough to specify that $x$ is in the domain of $\sec(x)$, so step 1 is not an error.

Comment: Actually on second reading the question does only ask if an error appears in any step. Whether an assumption counts as an error isn't quite clear to me. It could be interpreted either way.

Comment: Yes, I agree there is a question of interpretation. And I missed the part about $x$ being in the domain of $\sec(x)$ in the problem statement.

Comment: @SenZen yes. I can derive that using quotient rule. But I don't understand whether or not there's an error on the steps in the given problem. there seems no error at all because the steps arrived to $\sec(x) \tan(x)$. So is there an actually an error there? If so, why? Can you use a better explanation like a direct explanation , not using assumptions? I can't understand your previous explanation.

Comment: @harpey1111 "Is there an error there?" I can't answer because it depends on what you mean by an "error". Let me give you an analogy: Say Bob wants to simplify the fraction $\frac{16}{64}$. Bob sees that both the numerator and denominator have the number 6, so he just cancels them out and writes $\frac{1}{4}$. Done. Q) does Bob's method have an error?